# Draggable/Droppable: Cannot read updated data-* on draggable element in drop-event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Below is a simplified version of my code. Why does the `alert()` keeps saying `1`?
I can see that the HTML `data-count` gets updated up to `2` and then stops updating. Hope you can help me out.

```
<div class="product" data-count="1"></div>
```

```js
$(".product").draggable({ 
  helper: function(event) {
    return $(event.target).closest(".product").clone().css({
      width: $(event.target).width()
    });
  }
});

$(".panel-body").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.draggable.data("count"));
    ui.draggable.attr("data-count", ui.draggable.data("count") + 1);
    ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

Comment: Try `ui.draggable.data('count', ui.draggable.data('count') + 1);`

Comment: Sorry @RoryMcCrossan that does not work. We have to use `attr` to set the `data-*`. When I use my code above the HTML gets updated to `data-count="2"`. But the `alert()` still says 1. I do not know if this has something to do with cloning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$(".panel-body").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {    
    //ui.draggable.attr("data-count", ui.draggable.data("count") + 1);
    ui.draggable.data('count', ui.draggable.data('count') + 1);
    alert(ui.draggable.data("count"));
    ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

**[Online output (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/bmegy9st/)**